# Show failed stage in Jenkins stage view

Tags: jenkins

I'm configuring my first pipeline in Jenkins and I wonder why only the successful stages appear in the stage view?
Do I need to define that also failed stages appear there (e.g. in red)? If so, how would I do this?

[image: img]

The builds which failed appear without any color or information in the stage view (but in the build list left).
This is my pipeline configured online in Jenkins

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'servant2'
        }

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Jenkins says hello to the world'
            }
        }
        stage('Goodbye') {
            steps {
                echo 'Jenkins says goodbye to the world'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually that happens when the build doesn't start at all. If it fails during a step it should mark it automatically as red. Make sure you create a stage that will surely fail and test it that way.